# Knowing the availability of variables in crontab

Tags: unix, variables

What all variables BY DEFAULT are available if a script is executed by the crontab on UNIX Are .profile and oracle.env executed when the cron job is executed?

Answer (score 0):

> What all variables BY DEFAULT are
>   available if a script is executed by
>   the crontab on UNIX Are

You can find out by yourself ( as it might vary by platform ). Write yourself a simple script that gets executed by `cron` and dumps all environment variables in a temp file.

Comment: I appreciate this idea, but the problem is I can not manipulate the script executed by crom due to access restriction

Comment: I can't say for certain but it would appear that your options are limited then. Hopefully, somebody with more knowledge of cron will turn up a better answer than mine.  Note that it would help if you were to specify which platform we are talking about here.

Comment: I am executing the crom on AIX

Comment: I know nothing of AIX so my usefulness ends here. BTW, it is `cron` on most platforms - I didn't know it was `crom` on AIX.